# How to get the availability zone of Codebuild build during execution time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have an AWS Codebuild Project that is connected to a VPC. Now I'm trying to understand how can I get the availability zone of codebuild build during execution time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is an Environment Variable, CODEBUILD_VPC_AZ, that holds this value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html) there are two environment variables having the AWS Region where the build is running (`AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` and `AWS_REGION`). I don't think there is any possibility to get the actual availability zone.

But is there something specific that you want to achieve by knowing the availability zone? Maybe we can provide a solution to that.

Comment: The "complete" objective is to mount an EFS that is on another VPC.